# "Record is already updated, please re-query the block to see the change." in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracleforms

Whenever I try to update a field in oracle form after querying the record,I get an error
"Record is already updated,please re query the block to see the change."

The record does not get updated. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You get the message "Record is already updated, please requery the block to see the change." whenever the record is changed in the database.
For example you can query a record in a form and do a manual update in some trigger that fires when the query has been run (post-query, post-change, key-exeqry, ...)

And if you then try to lock the record when you update a field the message will appear because the record you are trying to change is outdated.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for ur reply....But pls provide some solution for this issue as I am unable to resolve this.

Comment: I can't give the solution, because it is in some trigger or some actions you are doing and I don't have that information.

Comment: I am using a standard set of procedures and triggers.Nothing on the customization side.